# Why the middle element in a sorted array is the majority element?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was doing [this question](https://leetcode.com/problems/majority-element/) in leetcode.

And i see a solution that i can't understand

It said "sort the array and the middle is the majority"

What i want to ask is

> "Why the middle element in a sorted array is the majority element?"

Could someone explain this thing?

This question's request:

> Given an array of size n, find the majority element. The majority element is the element that appears more than ⌊ n/2 ⌋ times.
>
> You may assume that the array is non-empty and the majority element always exist in the array.

Here is the answer's code:

```js
var majorityElement = function(nums) {
    // sort the array and the middle is the majority
    nums.sort((a,b) => a - b);
    return nums[Math.floor(nums.length/2)];
}; 
console.log(majorityElement([3,2,3]))
console.log(majorityElement([2,2,1,1,1,2,2]))
```

Comment: i think you missed the count the majority element has its always more than half of the element (n/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the inputted array *has* a majority element, it will occur at least `(n / 2) + 1` times in the array. If the majority element is the *lowest* number in the array, then the sorted array will look something like:

```
MMMMXX
  ^^ mid (even)
```

or

```
MMMMMXXX
    ^ mid (odd)
```

where `M` is the majority element, and X represents any other element. As you can see, `M` will always land on the middle of the array. If the majority element is the *highest* number in the array, then it would look something like:

```
XXMMMM
  ^^ mid (even)
```

or

```
XXXMMMM
    ^ mid (odd)
```

The `M` is still in the middle.

If `M` is neither the highest nor the lowest element in the array, then the sorted array will still have `M` in the middle, no matter how you try to shift the range around:

```
XXMMMM
XMMMMX
MMMMXX
  ^^
```

or

```
XXXMMMM
XXMMMMX
XMMMMXX
MMMMXXX
   ^
```

These examples are only for arrays of length 6 and 7, but the same idea applies to arrays of any size.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding.

Assume on the contrary that the middle element is not the majority element.
Hence the majority element is either to the right, or left of the middle element.
There are  `⌊ n/2 ⌋` elements to the left and `n - ⌊ n/2 ⌋` elements to the right.

Since the majority element is the element that appears more than `⌊ n/2 ⌋` times, it can neither be only to the left or right of the middle element  since both sides are `<= ⌊ n/2 ⌋` , and since a majority element exists, therefore it must include the middle element.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is if there is an element in the array which occurs more than n/2 times. after sorting the array. then the would passes through the midpoint that's why they are returning value at the index n/2